# How to prioritise selection of one column value over another on join?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, namely offers(containing columns `id` and `user_id`) and offer_maps (containing `offer_id`, `user_id`). I want to join both of the tables on `offer_id`, and the final selection should have `user_id` column populated by prioritising offer_maps' `user_id` column over offers' `user_id` column. For example, if offer_maps' `user_id` column is `null` and offers' `user_id` column has a value, the final `user_id` should have `offers`' `user_id` column. But if both are populated, then pick only offer_maps' `user_id` column value. How can I achieve this through sql query? Here's a sample which I wrote

```
select concat(offers.user_id, o.user_id) AS user_id
from offers
  left join offer_maps o on offers.id::text = o.offer_id
```

This actually joins both the values of columns, but I need only one in case both exist.

Comment: Hint:  `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL in this case:

```
select ISNULL (offers.user_id, o.user_id) AS user_id 
from offers 
left join offer_maps o on offers.id::text = o.offer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--This assumes O.user_id is not nullable, but OM.user_id is:
SELECT O.id[offer_id], ISNULL(O.user_id, OM.user_id)[user_id]
  FROM offers as O
  LEFT JOIN offer_maps as OM
    ON OM.offer_id = O.id
   AND ISNULL(OM.user_id, O.user_id) = O.user_id --Join when OM.user_id is null.
```

Comment: Note that `O.id[offer_id]` is invalid standard SQL, unless `o.id` is an array. In that case the expression gets the element from that array indicated by the value of the column `offer_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is valid T-SQL.  The OP refused to specify which DBMS they were working in, even when prompted.  Writing all my answers for the lowest-common-denominator because someone was lazy or forgot to post more details is not my responsibility.  He should be happy that I bothered to answer his question, but now I have to deal with him not even marking any answer as correct or why they were incorrect and with you complaining about how the syntax I used to define my aliases is not pure standard SQL.  How about you use your time to explain whether my answer is right or wrong?